# Register Instagram API error

Tags: api, instagram

Today i try to register my website and take Instagram API but see little changed page:

http://postimg.org/image/g4bssucyd/

there i can't add nothing for ''**redirect URI(s)**'' like before was,

When i add:

**application name**

**description**

**website url**

enter captcha, click on ''register'' nothing happend,
I ask Instagram support but they not answer, use google but nothing found, anyone here know something about this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also,  you must click over "Redirect URI(s)" so that show a input text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it seems like a bug. Sometimes it not works. Today (2015-04-15) I was facing a similar issue when registering my Client ID. When I filled up **Website URL** and **Redirect URI** with a public URL it just worked. Then I edited and changed to localhost url. So it work for me - although it's a bit weird...

Also, you must click on "`Redirect URI(s)`" so that show a input text:

[image]

And here is after I had changed redirect_uri public url to localhost:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably hadn't entered redirect urls, the text input is on the next line after the label "Redirect URI(s)" previously it was a single field, but now it supports multiple redirect urls. But there's really no point in that since Instagram API closed POST and DELETE methods for everyone (except some third party applications) Now you can only register your app with basic scope. Read the new policy they posted earlier:
http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests